# How to make Acrobat Reader DC remember the thumbnails between switching folders of Windows File Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have run into an issue with Acrobat Reader DC. My current system is now a few months old, during which I've used the regular Acrobat Reader for my PDF files. It used to generate thumbnails just fine, but since a day or two it stopped generating thumbnails for new PDF files, even with reinstalls. As such, I've moved to using Acrobat Reader DC which generates them, if a bit slowly.

The issue is that while Acrobat Reader DC generates them just fine, the moment I go to another folder using the Windows File Explorer and return to the initial one, anywhere from a half-dozen to almost all PDFs in a folder (which can be several dozen and in a few approach 100) require their thumbnails to be reloaded. If this took only a couple of seconds I might have been able to accept this, but given that this is not the case (thumbnails are generated at speeds ranging between 2 to 4 thumbnails per second) and that the regular Acrobat Reader was able to remember them just fine I am looking for a solution to this problem. As far as I know I have not made any significant alterations to my system since this problem started, nor have the PDFs themselves changed. Do I have to change settings within Acrobat Reader DC, or perhaps something for my system?

I have googled this problem already, but the things I have found have to do with either getting thumbnails to work in the first place, the questions are a few years old or they make it unable to move around, copy or delete the PDF files. How do I go about fixing this?

My system runs on 64-bit Windows 10, and the version of Acrobat Reader DC I use is 2017.012.20093, which is as of writing the most current version of the program. If possible I'd like to stick with Acrobat Reader, but if this is not possible then so be it.